# How can I capture the internal LAN IP address using javascript

Tags: javascript

First post need some help.  I'm building an internal network that has a series of iPads that are being used to control my house.  I'm building a website that is using javascript to send out serial control commands to different devices connected to my server.  I want to have 5 ipads in 5 different rooms.  Each with a home page of different controls.  So the controls for my bedroom are going to be different than the controls for my living room etc...However on each of my ipads I"m going to have a nav bar that will allow me to page jump to a different room for control.  The thing i'm stuck on is I'd like to be able to click on a home button on any of the pages in any of the rooms and have that room's ipad be automatically redirected back to the home page that is specific to the ipad in that room.  The only way I can see to do this is to set a static ip on each ipad and have the home button go back to index.html where the ip address of the requesting ipad is read and then redirected to teh correct home page for that ipad based on its static ip address.  The kicker is I can't use php.  I can use .asp but I don't know asp.  If someone can help that would be fantastic.  I grabbed a code snippet from a different post but the result keeps giving me my external IP which is worthless for what I'm trying to do.  see below.  The other thought I had was registering each ipad on first connect via a form with a specific name and saving that info as a cookie.  Each time the ipad goes to index.html the cookie is read and then redirected accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function myIP() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
    else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://jsonip.appspot.com/",false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    hostipInfo = xmlhttp.responseText;
    obj = JSON.parse(hostipInfo);
    document.getElementById("IP").value=obj.ip;
    document.getElementById("ADDRESS").value=obj.address;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myIP()">
    IP :<input type="text" id="IP" name="IP" />
ADDRESS :<input type="text" id="ADDRESS" name="ADDRESS" />
```

Comment: is your webserver on your LAN ?

Comment: You don't, but the IP is sent to the server when the user makes a request. You send it to the server and then have it send it back. Also, like lostsource is saying, your server would have to be _inside_ the LAN.

Comment: You could use HTML5 local storage to store the necessary configuration or state for each ipad. Write a script to check for that config object and prompt the user for a default profile if it doesn't exist yet. Once you know the configuration you can asynchronously load the correct HTML elements e.g. with `$('#jQuerySelector').load('/path.php', {panelName:'bedroom1'})`

Answer (score 0):

Deciding which controls to display based on an external factor (the IP) is a bit inflexible and maybe to much trouble for little gain.

I more friendly way would be a little button/checkbox on your page to indicate which controls belong to the device. Effectively setting that page as the homepage.

Just like @Plato said in his comment you could use cookies, [local- or session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage) to persist the configuration state. The best bet is to use `localStorage` since it doesn't expire.

Comment: thanks guys...I'll give these a shot.  I just tried a JS cookie store and it works but I like the HTML 5 local store idea better I'll give that one a shot.